# A function by type? How refactor it?

Tags: go, refactoring

I'm reading json data from a file and sending it to a remote server using gob encoding,
but I'm not happy with my code, I tried several ways to get a more generic function, but I'm failed, the only way that my code works is having identical functions for every type.

I tried using switch for types, but in the same way is needed repeat code in order to unmarshall and encode gob data

Please, could somebody help me to understand how improve that?

Two types:

```
type Data1 struct{
ID int
Message string
}

type Data2 struct{
 Serial int
 Height float64
 Loss   float64
 Temp   float64
 Oil    float64
}
```

Function for Data1 type

```
func SenderData1(address string, buff *filebuffer.Buffer) {
    var conn net.Conn
    var err error
    var line string
    var obj Data1
    for {
        line, err = buff.Pop()
        if err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Poping:", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        if len(line) == 0 {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            continue
        }
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(line), &obj); err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Unmarshaling:", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        for {
            log.Info("Trying to connect with Server...")
            conn, err = net.Dial(PROTO, address)
            // If err try to connect again
            if err != nil {
                log.Error("Error connecting:", err.Error())
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                continue
            }
            // If connected break the loop
            break
        }
        log.Debug("Sending ", obj, " to:", address)

        encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
        err := encoder.Encode(obj)
        if err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Encoding Gob:", err.Error())
        }
        // Timer between every sending, ie. Reading from buffer
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        conn.Close()
    }
}
```

The same function but for Data2 type

```
func SenderData2(address string, buff *filebuffer.Buffer) {
    var conn net.Conn
    var err error
    var line string
    var obj Data2
    for {
        line, err = buff.Pop()
        if err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Poping:", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        if len(line) == 0 {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            continue
        }
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(line), &obj); err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Unmarshaling:", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        for {
            log.Info("Trying to connect with Server...")
            conn, err = net.Dial(PROTO, address)
            // If err try to connect again
            if err != nil {
                log.Error("Error connecting:", err.Error())
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                continue
            }
            // If connected break the loop
            break
        }
        log.Debug("Sending ", obj, " to:", address)

        encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
        err := encoder.Encode(obj)
        if err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Encoding Gob:", err.Error())
        }
        // Timer between every sending, ie. Reading from buffer
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        conn.Close()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter that allocates a new value of the type to receive and send:

```
func SenderData1(address string, buff *filebuffer.Buffer) {
    SenderData(address, buff, func() interface{} { return new(Data1) })
}

func SenderData2(address string, buff *filebuffer.Buffer) {
    SenderData(address, buff, func() interface{} { return new(Data2) })
}

func SenderData(address string, buff *filebuffer.Buffer, newfn func() interface{}) {
    var conn net.Conn
    var err error
    var line string
    for {
        line, err = buff.Pop()
        if err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Poping:", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        if len(line) == 0 {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            continue
        }
        obj := newfn()
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(line), obj); err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Unmarshaling:", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        for {
            log.Info("Trying to connect with Server...")
            conn, err = net.Dial(PROTO, address)
            // If err try to connect again
            if err != nil {
                log.Error("Error connecting:", err.Error())
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                continue
            }
            // If connected break the loop
            break
        }
        log.Debug("Sending ", obj, " to:", address)

        encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
        err := encoder.Encode(obj)
        if err != nil {
            log.Critical("Error Encoding Gob:", err.Error())
        }
        // Timer between every sending, ie. Reading from buffer
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        conn.Close()
    }
}
```

The code in this answer allocates a new value every time through the loop while the code in the question allocates the object once.  Allocating each time through the loop prevents crosstalk between received JSON objects.

Comment: How can I name that way? I'd never figured out something like that.

Comment: I have the same problem with functions that have channels as parameters, can I do the same with functions like that?